# can't UPDATE User using mysql navicat c#

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

how to update user on navicat using c# visual studio
when i click the picture button it can't update user

```
Activity = "";

Con.InitializeConnection(Server, "maternal");

string add = textBox9.Text + " " + textBox10.Text + " " + textBox11.Text;

string sql = "UPDATE tb_maternal_masterlist SET lname = '" + textBox2.Text + "', fname='" + textBox3.Text + "', mname='" + textBox4.Text +
                      "', age='" + textBox5.Text + "', birth='" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "', occupation='" + textBox6.Text + "', sex='" + textBox7.Text +
                      "', marital='" + comboBox2.Text + "', zip='" + textBox8.Text + "', address='" + add + "', street='" + textBox9.Text +
                      "', barangay='" + textBox10.Text + "', city='" + textBox11.Text + "', hlname='" + textBox12.Text + "', hfname='" + textBox13.Text +
                      "', hmname='" + textBox14.Text + "', hsuffix='" + textBox15.Text + "', hage='" + textBox16.Text + "', hoccupation='" + textBox17.Text +
                      "', hcontact='" + textBox18.Text + "', religion='" + textBox1.Text + "', " + "marriage='" + textBox49.Text + "', hreligion='" + textBox48.Text +
                      "', nocba='" + textBox19.Text + "', nocbl='" + textBox20.Text + "', noa='" + textBox21.Text + "', nosb='" + textBox22.Text +
                      "', familyplanning='" + cbx1.Text + "', method='" + textBox23.Text + "', willing='" + cbx2.Text + "', menshistory='" + textBox46.Text +
                      "', gravida='" + textBox40.Text + "', " + "para='" + textBox41.Text + "', hemorage='" + cbx3.Text + "', toxemia='" + cbx4.Text +
                      "', placenta='" + cbx5.Text + "', sepsis='" + cbx6.Text + "', famhistory='" + textBox42.Text + "', nausea='" + cbx7.Text +
                      "', vomiting='" + cbx8.Text + "', headache='" + cbx9.Text + "', dizziness='" + cbx10.Text + "', edema='" + cbx11.Text + "', pruritus='" + cbx12.Text +
                      "', " + "constipation='" + cbx13.Text + "', cramps='" + cbx14.Text + "', bleeding='" + cbx15.Text + "', leucorrhea='" + cbx16.Text +
                      "', indigestion='" + cbx17.Text + "', blurring='" + cbx18.Text + "', lastmens='" + textBox24.Text + "', expectmens='" + textBox25.Text +
                      "', aptype='" + cbx19.Text + "', riskcode='" + textBox26.Text + "', " + "lastdelivery='" + textBox27.Text +
                      "', placedelivery='" + textBox28.Text + "', tt1='" + textBox29.Text + "', tt2='" + textBox30.Text + "', tt3='" + textBox31.Text +
                      "', tt4='" + textBox32.Text + "', tt5='" + textBox33.Text + "', special='" + textBox47.Text + "' where pincode='" + FUCKINGPINCODE + "'";

Con.UpdateData(Con.ConString, sql);

Activity = "Updating Patient Info and History";

MessageBox.Show("PATIENT INFO AND HISTORY SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED!");
SaveActivity();
this.Close();
```

Comment: What does the generated SQL query look like? What are the methods `.InitializeConnection` and `.UpdateData` ?

Comment: You should use [parameterized queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?source=recommendations&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) to avoid SQL injections and other issues

Comment: And I strongly suggest you to name correctly your controls. Giving meaningful naming will help you maintain your code

Comment: Don't concatenate user input to create queries. Imagine what would happen if one of those fields contained `' #`. Ooops, all rows got updated with the same value. Or `'; DROP TABLE Users; #`. Use parameterized queries instead. It's a *lot* easier and cleaner to do so than trying to guess what `sql` actually contains